# rsync succeeds of fails depending on the destination directory

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I am conducting both experiments below with empty `/home/pantelis` folder (which is the destination directory)

This command succeeds:

```
rsync -zalP --progress --exclude=.git --exclude=.vscode /Users/pantelis/Workspace/my-work/terragrunt/modules/ my-server:/home/pantelis/my-work/
```

i.e. on `my-server`, `my-work` directory is created and has the contents of `/Users/pantelis/Workspace/my-work/terragrunt/modules/`

On the remote machine, I now delete `/home/pantelis/my-work` so `/home/pantelis` is once again empty.

I try to run the `rsync` command as follows which now fails

```
▶ rsync -zalP --progress --exclude=.git --exclude=.vscode /Users/pantelis/Workspace/my-work/terragrunt/modules/ my-server:/home/pantelis/my-work/terragrunt/modules/
building file list ...
1114 files to consider
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/d7e177bcf5/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I am trying this since, apparently I want the remote file structure to match the local one.

Why is it failing in the second attempt?

It it because for (some inherent reason) `rsync` cannot create any other dir than the leaf? (`my-work`)? In that case I have tried the `--relative` option as suggested [here](http://%E2%96%B6%20rsync%20-zalP%20--progress%20--exclude=.git%20--exclude=.vscode%20/Users/pantelis/Workspace/systems-terraform/terragrunt/modules/%20stg2-admin:/home/pantelis/systems-terraform/terragrunt/modules/%20building%20file%20list%20...%201114%20files%20to%20consider%20rsync:%20connection%20unexpectedly%20closed%20(8%20bytes%20received%20so%20far)%20%5Bsender%5D%20rsync%20error:%20error%20in%20rsync%20protocol%20data%20stream%20(code%2012)%20at%20/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/d7e177bcf5/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/io.c(453)%20%5Bsender=2.6.9%5D) but with no success whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your command to create missing directory hierarchy on my-server:

```
--rsync-path="mkdir -p /home/pantelis/my-work/terragrunt/modules/ && rsync"
```